# Restricting Dates Using Custom Options - Input Type Date

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, frontend, date

I'm looking to add in an estimated delivery date field on to the product pages of my magento store - I'm currently using a custom option within the product to control this with the date input type.

Is there anyway to stop a user from entering a date that has already passed and remove any dates that aren't available such as weekends and holidays?

I'm currently running Magento 1.8 should it make any difference

[image: Product Options On the Front End]